# Keep printed documents on Windows Server 2008 R2 Print Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, printing

I've setup Windows 2008 R2 as print server. I have checked option Keep printed document option for all printers and it works fine. Users print their stuff and i can see what they are doing.

Problem is everyone sees all documents that are getting printed which is not always the best idea.

Is there a way to:

1. Limit print jobs to be only seen by people who printed them and admins
2. Limit print jobs to be only seen on server (from within Server Manager) and so print jobs dissapear when print job is done from user queue (but then admins are still able to see it and track what's printed and when for reporting purposes).
3. Create some kind of access level list so that some people can see everything geting printed, some people see their print jobs and some people see nothing :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to fix this by using following procedure:

1. Server Manager -> Diagnostics -> Event Views (*or `compmgmt.msc` => Event Viewer*)
2. Applications and Service Logs -> Microsoft
3. Windows -> PrintServer -> Operational
4. Right click on the right side under Actions "Enable Log"

And then you can monitor who printed what. You can create Custom View out of it for convenience using Event ID 307 to monitor just printed jobs.