# Is it possible to prevent users from removing jobs from the print queue?

Tags: windows, permissions, printing

I need to log all printed documents with their contents. I've enabled "Keep printed documents" in the relevant printers' properties. Now, I'm trying to prevent users from removing jobs from the printer queue.

I've been trying to implement this by changing the permissions of `C:\windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS` by denying "delete" permissions for the target user account, but without success.

Does what I'm trying to do make sense? Is it possible?

Comment: local or shared printers?

Comment: @BlueCompute local

Comment: Also note that using third party solutions is not an option. My workplace is as strict about comercial licensing as it is stingy. There is no chance of convincing them to pay for more software.

Comment: Be much easier if you pushed everything through a central printserver.

Comment: As far as I know a Windows print server does not have an archiving option. Possibly you could write something like a powershell script or small C# service monitoring the spool directory for changes (copying new files to an archiving location). Is it possible this simplification would serve your need instead? http://serverfault.com/questions/144679/keep-printed-documents-on-windows-server-2008-r2-print-server

Comment: What about if you set the permissions to the printer?

Comment: I do think the print queue would make for a lousy archive, a bit like using the thrash as an achive for mail.

Comment: To be honest, I'm well aware that keeping print jobs indefinitly is not an elagent solution, but I don't know what else to do. If no solution is posted, I'll probably learn powershell and write a solution as @ErikE suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand & clarify your question a bit more as you can tell from all these questions in the comments. I agree with @KonradGajewski; if you go to Printer Properties (I'm on Win7), on Security tab you have a bit of control over local shared printers. Sadly it appears Print rights allows users to cancel ones on jobs (search 'Permissions):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727107.aspx

I'm guessing there is no easy way to stop user from canceling/deleting their own jobs. It does seem a task scheduler script copying files elsewhere is your best bet. If you're just wanting accountability, you can get a log from enabling Event Viewer->Application and Server Logs->Microsoft->Microsoft->Windows->PrintService, right-click Operational, Enable Log